# Mysql is very slow vs mariadb

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

Query

```
select * from pmt_bolok 
where id in (select max(id) from  pmt_bolok 
            group by bolok_row)
```

This query in MariaDB(10.0.17) execute very nice in 0.094 sec. (+ 0.047 sec. network)

But in mysql(5.5.32) is very slow in 00:05:44 sec. (+ 478 sec. network)

My table is innodb and `id` field is primary key.

all my.ini is equal except port and mysql path

```
[client] 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
autocommit=1
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

server-id   = 1

innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M

innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

**Question:**

Why speed this query is very very slow in mysql?

How can increment speed this query in mysql?

Except my.ini what is different between mysql and mariadb?

Comment: Neat story. What's your question?

Comment: why speed this query is very very slow in mysql?

Except my.ini what is different between mysql and mariadb?

Comment: I'm guessing you may want to rewrite the query to do an `inner join` instead of an `in subquery` but since there's no sqlfiddle, i cant try it to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving to MySQL 5.7 or rewrite your query to

```
select * from pmt_bolok order by id desc limit 1
```

As for why it happens - MySQL 5.5 doesn't have subquery result materialization and subquery in your WHERE clause will be executed for each row in the table.

Comment: `select * from pmt_bolok 
where id in (select max(id) from  pmt_bolok 
            group by bolok_row)  ` how can write this query with out sub query?

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` optimized *very* poorly in 5.5 and before.

You have a [*Groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) type of query.  See that link for better performance in any version.

As for your settings, "you cannot tune your way out of a performance problem".  However, assuming you are using InnoDB, you should set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* RAM.  That will help all queries.  If you are using MyISAM, well, you should not.